# Xamarin Forms Shell covering top information line on iOS (iPad)

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, padding, xamarin.shell

I have a Xamarin Forms app using the new Shell feature.  My problem now is that the shell menu area (Hamburger menu area at the top) is covered by my app and I would rather it not be.

Here is what I am talking about.

[image]

You can see the area with the Data and Time at the top is covered in the second image from my app.  I would like that to not be the case.

In other apps I have done this on content pages:

```
<ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
        <On Platform="iOS">8,20,8,0</On>
        <On Platform="Android">8,0,8,0</On>
        <On Platform="UWP">8,0,8,0</On>
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentPage.Padding>
```

and in the Shell page I have tried:

```
<Shell.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
        <On Platform="iOS">8,20,8,0</On>
        <On Platform="Android">8,0,8,0</On>
        <On Platform="UWP">8,0,8,0</On>
    </OnPlatform>
</Shell.Padding>
```

but it makes no difference.  Any idea how make the date / time are not overlaid by the Shell menu?

UPDATE:
After applying the iOS Safe areas as described below, the app appears to look the same to me:

[image]

The background behind the data and time is still the background color of the shell header (i.e. black) so you can't really see them.  I want the shell to move down so the users can still see the date / time on left, network / charge indicators on the right.

Comment: Umm I am not sure what is the issue the screenshots do not seem to have a difference!

Comment: @FreakyAli if you look at the second picture you can see the dark background color of the top of the Shell menu goes all the way to the top of the screen going over the date / time etc.

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr Sorry for not understanding your needs . You can share a wanted image to explain , it will be helpful .

Comment: @JuniorJiang, the top iPad cut out in the first image is what I am looking for.  I want the shell (and its background) to not go up into the Date / Time, network / power areas at the very top of the screen.

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr Okey , I have shared a workaround in answer .

Comment: That is why you should always choose native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround by modifying Status Bar Text Color to mark it. If your app navigation background color always keep dark style , this workaround will be no problem .However it is not a perfect solution .Because it can not be modified back runtime. Before finding the best solution , you can have a try with it .

The **Workaround** is need to open **Info.plist** in iOS solution ,

[image]

Adding two key-values to modify the style of Status Bar Content ,

```
<string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
```

[image]

Then even color of navigation bar is black , the text color of staus bar will be saw.

[image]

Second **Workaround** : (Better than first one)

Also need to open **Info.plist** in iOS solution ,but just add one key-value inside it.

```
<string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Then in `AppDelegate.cs` add method to set background color of status bar to be `White` color.

```
public override void OnActivated(UIApplication uiApplication)
{
    base.OnActivated(uiApplication);
    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
    {
        // If VS has updated to the latest version , you can use StatusBarManager , else use the first line code
        // UIView statusBar = new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame);
        UIView statusBar = new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene.StatusBarManager.StatusBarFrame);
        statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        //statusBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.AddSubview(statusBar);
    }
    else
    {
        UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
        if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
        {
            statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
            //statusBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.BlackOpaque;
        }
    }
}
```

Image as follow :

[image]

The effect:

[image]

Note : If finding better workaround later will update here.

Comment: Thanks @JuiorJiang.  I will let you know how I make out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 11 and above i would highly recommend you try to set the Safe Area in iOS, it's fairly simple and might fix your problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout

Comment: thanks for the info.  I will be sure to include this in my app but it did not address the challenge I am trying to resolve.  I posted a screen shot above of what the page looks like with the safe area implemented.  I look just like it did before.  Please see update above for screen shot.

Comment: sorry it didn't work out like this, i forgot that you can change the appearance of the system bar. You should check out the answer from Junior Jiang, i think this one will guide you to the right direction